# After sending mail with nodemailer page starts loading without actually changing elements/the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have this basic form in a react component:

```
<form method="POST" action="/sendcontact" encType="multipart/form-data" className="contact-form">
     <label>* Your name</label>
     <input 
        type="text"
        name="username"
        placeholder="Your name" 
        required
     />
     <label>* E-mail</label>
     <input 
        type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Your e-mail"
        required
      />
      <label>* Message</label>
      <textarea 
         name="message"
         placeholder="Your message here..."
         required
      />
      <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

index.js (node)

```
app.post('/sendcontact',(req,res) => {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.end("Something went wrong!");
        }else{            
            let mailOptions = {
                from: req.body.email,
                to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
                subject: `New message from ${req.body.email}`,
                text: req.body.message
            };
              
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

The mail successfully sends, but after submitting the form, the page starts loading forever basically, unless I manually stop it. By loading I mean just on the web tab, next to the name of the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eQ0s.jpg

I really can't figure out what could be causing this but I want to fix it, so users won't think that something is actually happening because the page starts loading.

I have noticed that it doesn't behave like this if in the React component I use state to store the form values and send them to node via axios, but I can't do this, as I will have to send the value of an input[type="file"] too and I haven't figured out how to do that with axios yet.

Comment: In `app.post('/sendcontact'` you only respond if there was an error `return res.end("Something went wrong!");` but you also need to respond when there was no error. Add something like `res.json({ success: true })` to the callback of `transporter.sendMail` function. The browser basicaly waiting for response from server and doesn't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time we make a request to the server, the browser waits for a response (as mentioned in comments by Molda).

Basically, after the form is submitted, sending an `http.post` to `'/sendcontact'`, no error is invoked inside your controller to enter the `if(err)`. Which means your server doesn't return any response in the form of `res.end(), res.send(), res.json() or res.redirect()` back to the user's browser.

A good practice would be redirecting it to a success page, calling the `res.redirect('/<wanted path'>)` inside of `transporter.sendMail`, in case of success, or simple redirect to a default page after you close the `trasporter.sendMail` function.